# Can anyone help identify the LEGO bags, lime, dark green, and dark grey?

Tags: set-identification, instructions

I have 3 bags of LEGO. I need the instructions. Can anyone help?

[image] [image] [image] [image] [image]

Answer (score 3):

These bags are from 
[9457-1: Fangpyre Wrecking Ball](https://brickset.com/sets/9457-1/Fangpyre-Wrecking-Ball)

[image]

Based on

- [Track Element, 5X1,5](https://brickset.com/sets/containing-part-4566742)
- [4625623: Cupboard 2X3X2](https://brickset.com/parts/4625623/cupboard-2x3x2)
- and the multiple other Bright Yellowish Green parts

Comment: Joost, thank you so much! we bought used Lego for our kids and got unopened Lego bags from time to time. This is going to make their day. Thanks again.